# Is there a SBT plugin for Sphinx?

Tags: maven, sbt, python-sphinx, docbook

A lot of people out there argue Sphinx is an amazing documentation tool... so I've decided to give it a look. I use to write my technical documents in DocBook and to generate HTML/PDF output with a Maven plugin (Docbkx) - I just need to install Maven, set the needed dependencies, et voilà, I get everything I need.

Back to Sphinx... is there a SBT plugin that let me produce HTML/PDF output in the same way I do with DocBook/Maven?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a plugin directly from SBT developers: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-site#sphinx-site-generation